# I am getting this error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'). Any advice on how to overcome it

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am getting this error consistently when using TensorFlow to run the original PINNs file for Schrodinger equations. The machine says the error is on line 247 (with [] in the code), but the code here;

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../../Utilities/')

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from pyDOE import lhs
from plotting import newfig, savefig
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


np.random.seed(1234)
tf.set_random_seed(np.random.seed)


class PhysicsInformedNN:
    # Initialize the class
    def __init__(self, x0, u0, v0, tb, X_f, layers, lb, ub):
        
        X0 = np.concatenate((x0, 0*x0), 1) # (x0, 0)
        X_lb = np.concatenate((0*tb + lb[0], tb), 1) # (lb[0], tb)
        X_ub = np.concatenate((0*tb + ub[0], tb), 1) # (ub[0], tb)
        
        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
               
        self.x0 = X0[:,0:1]
        self.t0 = X0[:,1:2]

        self.x_lb = X_lb[:,0:1]
        self.t_lb = X_lb[:,1:2]

        self.x_ub = X_ub[:,0:1]
        self.t_ub = X_ub[:,1:2]
        
        self.x_f = X_f[:,0:1]
        self.t_f = X_f[:,1:2]
        
        self.u0 = u0
        self.v0 = v0
        
        # Initialize NNs
        self.layers = layers
        self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_NN(layers)
        
        # tf Placeholders        
        self.x0_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x0.shape[1]])
        self.t0_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t0.shape[1]])
        
        self.u0_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.u0.shape[1]])
        self.v0_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.v0.shape[1]])
        
        self.x_lb_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x_lb.shape[1]])
        self.t_lb_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t_lb.shape[1]])
        
        self.x_ub_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x_ub.shape[1]])
        self.t_ub_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t_ub.shape[1]])
        
        self.x_f_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x_f.shape[1]])
        self.t_f_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t_f.shape[1]])

        # tf Graphs
        self.u0_pred, self.v0_pred, _ , _ = self.net_uv(self.x0_tf, self.t0_tf)
        self.u_lb_pred, self.v_lb_pred, self.u_x_lb_pred, self.v_x_lb_pred = self.net_uv(self.x_lb_tf, self.t_lb_tf)
        self.u_ub_pred, self.v_ub_pred, self.u_x_ub_pred, self.v_x_ub_pred = self.net_uv(self.x_ub_tf, self.t_ub_tf)
        self.f_u_pred, self.f_v_pred = self.net_f_uv(self.x_f_tf, self.t_f_tf)
        
        # Loss
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u0_tf - self.u0_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v0_tf - self.v0_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u_lb_pred - self.u_ub_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_lb_pred - self.v_ub_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.u_x_lb_pred - self.u_x_ub_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v_x_lb_pred - self.v_x_ub_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_u_pred)) + \
                    tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.f_v_pred))
        
        # Optimizers
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.estimator.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(self.loss, 
                                                                method = 'L-BFGS-B', 
                                                                options = {'maxiter': 50000,
                                                                           'maxfun': 50000,
                                                                           'maxcor': 50,
                                                                           'maxls': 50,
                                                                           'ftol' : 1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps})
    
        self.optimizer_Adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        self.train_op_Adam = self.optimizer_Adam.minimize(self.loss)
                
        # tf session
        self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                                     log_device_placement=True))
        
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess.run(init)
              
    def initialize_NN(self, layers):        
        weights = []
        biases = []
        num_layers = len(layers) 
        for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
            W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
            b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
            weights.append(W)
            biases.append(b)        
        return weights, biases
        
    def xavier_init(self, size):
        in_dim = size[0]
        out_dim = size[1]        
        xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim))
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)
    
    def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
        num_layers = len(weights) + 1
        
        H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
        for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
            W = weights[l]
            b = biases[l]
            H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))
        W = weights[-1]
        b = biases[-1]
        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b)
        return Y
    
    def net_uv(self, x, t):
        X = tf.concat([x,t],1)
        
        uv = self.neural_net(X, self.weights, self.biases)
        u = uv[:,0:1]
        v = uv[:,1:2]
        
        u_x = tf.gradients(u, x)[0]
        v_x = tf.gradients(v, x)[0]

        return u, v, u_x, v_x

    def net_f_uv(self, x, t):
        u, v, u_x, v_x = self.net_uv(x,t)
        
        u_t = tf.gradients(u, t)[0]
        u_xx = tf.gradients(u_x, x)[0]
        
        v_t = tf.gradients(v, t)[0]
        v_xx = tf.gradients(v_x, x)[0]
        
        f_u = u_t + 0.5*v_xx + (u**2 + v**2)*v
        f_v = v_t - 0.5*u_xx - (u**2 + v**2)*u   
        
        return f_u, f_v
    
    def callback(self, loss):
        print('Loss:', loss)
        
    def train(self, nIter):
        
        tf_dict = {self.x0_tf: self.x0, self.t0_tf: self.t0,
                   self.u0_tf: self.u0, self.v0_tf: self.v0,
                   self.x_lb_tf: self.x_lb, self.t_lb_tf: self.t_lb,
                   self.x_ub_tf: self.x_ub, self.t_ub_tf: self.t_ub,
                   self.x_f_tf: self.x_f, self.t_f_tf: self.t_f}
        
        start_time = time.time()
        for it in range(nIter):
            self.sess.run(self.train_op_Adam, tf_dict)
            
            # Print
            if it % 10 == 0:
                elapsed = time.time() - start_time
                loss_value = self.sess.run(self.loss, tf_dict)
                print('It: %d, Loss: %.3e, Time: %.2f' % 
                      (it, loss_value, elapsed))
                start_time = time.time()
                                                                                                                          
        self.optimizer.minimize(self.sess, 
                                feed_dict = tf_dict,         
                                fetches = [self.loss], 
                                loss_callback = self.callback)        
                                    
    
    def predict(self, X_star):
        
        tf_dict = {self.x0_tf: X_star[:,0:1], self.t0_tf: X_star[:,1:2]}
        
        u_star = self.sess.run(self.u0_pred, tf_dict)  
        v_star = self.sess.run(self.v0_pred, tf_dict)  
        
        
        tf_dict = {self.x_f_tf: X_star[:,0:1], self.t_f_tf: X_star[:,1:2]}
        
        f_u_star = self.sess.run(self.f_u_pred, tf_dict)
        f_v_star = self.sess.run(self.f_v_pred, tf_dict)
               
        return u_star, v_star, f_u_star, f_v_star
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
     
    noise = 0.0        
    
    # Doman bounds
    lb = np.array([-5.0, 0.0])
    ub = np.array([5.0, np.pi/2])

    N0 = 50
    N_b = 50
    N_f = 20000
    layers = [2, 100, 100, 100, 100, 2]
        
    data = scipy.io.loadmat('../Data/NLS.mat')
    
    t = data['tt'].flatten()[:,None]
    x = data['x'].flatten()[:,None]
    Exact = data['uu']
    Exact_u = np.real(Exact)
    Exact_v = np.imag(Exact)
    Exact_h = np.sqrt(Exact_u**2 + Exact_v**2)
    
    X, T = np.meshgrid(x,t)
    
    X_star = np.hstack((X.flatten()[:,None], T.flatten()[:,None]))
    u_star = Exact_u.T.flatten()[:,None]
    v_star = Exact_v.T.flatten()[:,None]
    h_star = Exact_h.T.flatten()[:,None]
    
    ###########################
    
    idx_x = np.random.choice(x.shape[0], N0, replace=False)
    x0 = x[idx_x,:]
    u0 = Exact_u[idx_x,0:1]
    v0 = Exact_v[idx_x,0:1]
    
    idx_t = np.random.choice(t.shape[0], N_b, replace=False)
    tb = t[idx_t,:]
    
    X_f = lb + (ub-lb)*lhs(2, N_f)
            
    []model = PhysicsInformedNN(x0, u0, v0, tb, X_f, layers, lb, ub)
             
    start_time = time.time()                
    model.train(50000)
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time                
    print('Training time: %.4f' % (elapsed))[]
    
        
    u_pred, v_pred, f_u_pred, f_v_pred = model.predict(X_star)
    h_pred = np.sqrt(u_pred**2 + v_pred**2)
            
    error_u = np.linalg.norm(u_star-u_pred,2)/np.linalg.norm(u_star,2)
    error_v = np.linalg.norm(v_star-v_pred,2)/np.linalg.norm(v_star,2)
    error_h = np.linalg.norm(h_star-h_pred,2)/np.linalg.norm(h_star,2)
    print('Error u: %e' % (error_u))
    print('Error v: %e' % (error_v))
    print('Error h: %e' % (error_h))

    
    U_pred = griddata(X_star, u_pred.flatten(), (X, T), method='cubic')
    V_pred = griddata(X_star, v_pred.flatten(), (X, T), method='cubic')
    H_pred = griddata(X_star, h_pred.flatten(), (X, T), method='cubic')

    FU_pred = griddata(X_star, f_u_pred.flatten(), (X, T), method='cubic')
    FV_pred = griddata(X_star, f_v_pred.flatten(), (X, T), method='cubic')     
    

    
    ######################################################################
    ############################# Plotting ###############################
    ######################################################################    
    
    X0 = np.concatenate((x0, 0*x0), 1) # (x0, 0)
    X_lb = np.concatenate((0*tb + lb[0], tb), 1) # (lb[0], tb)
    X_ub = np.concatenate((0*tb + ub[0], tb), 1) # (ub[0], tb)
    X_u_train = np.vstack([X0, X_lb, X_ub])

    fig, ax = newfig(1.0, 0.9)
    ax.axis('off')
    
    ####### Row 0: h(t,x) ##################    
    gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
    gs0.update(top=1-0.06, bottom=1-1/3, left=0.15, right=0.85, wspace=0)
    ax = plt.subplot(gs0[:, :])
    
    h = ax.imshow(H_pred.T, interpolation='nearest', cmap='YlGnBu', 
                  extent=[lb[1], ub[1], lb[0], ub[0]], 
                  origin='lower', aspect='auto')
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    fig.colorbar(h, cax=cax)
    
    ax.plot(X_u_train[:,1], X_u_train[:,0], 'kx', label = 'Data (%d points)' % (X_u_train.shape[0]), markersize = 4, clip_on = False)
    
    line = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 2)[:,None]
    ax.plot(t[75]*np.ones((2,1)), line, 'k--', linewidth = 1)
    ax.plot(t[100]*np.ones((2,1)), line, 'k--', linewidth = 1)
    ax.plot(t[125]*np.ones((2,1)), line, 'k--', linewidth = 1)    
    
    ax.set_xlabel('$t$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$x$')
    leg = ax.legend(frameon=False, loc = 'best')
#    plt.setp(leg.get_texts(), color='w')
    ax.set_title('$|h(t,x)|$', fontsize = 10)
    
    ####### Row 1: h(t,x) slices ##################    
    gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3)
    gs1.update(top=1-1/3, bottom=0, left=0.1, right=0.9, wspace=0.5)
    
    ax = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
    ax.plot(x,Exact_h[:,75], 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Exact')       
    ax.plot(x,H_pred[75,:], 'r--', linewidth = 2, label = 'Prediction')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$|h(t,x)|$')    
    ax.set_title('$t = %.2f$' % (t[75]), fontsize = 10)
    ax.axis('square')
    ax.set_xlim([-5.1,5.1])
    ax.set_ylim([-0.1,5.1])
    
    ax = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 1])
    ax.plot(x,Exact_h[:,100], 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Exact')       
    ax.plot(x,H_pred[100,:], 'r--', linewidth = 2, label = 'Prediction')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$|h(t,x)|$')
    ax.axis('square')
    ax.set_xlim([-5.1,5.1])
    ax.set_ylim([-0.1,5.1])
    ax.set_title('$t = %.2f$' % (t[100]), fontsize = 10)
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.8), ncol=5, frameon=False)
    
    ax = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 2])
    ax.plot(x,Exact_h[:,125], 'b-', linewidth = 2, label = 'Exact')       
    ax.plot(x,H_pred[125,:], 'r--', linewidth = 2, label = 'Prediction')
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$|h(t,x)|$')
    ax.axis('square')
    ax.set_xlim([-5.1,5.1])
    ax.set_ylim([-0.1,5.1])    
    ax.set_title('$t = %.2f$' % (t[125]), fontsize = 10)
    
    # savefig('./figures/NLS')
```

seems not to have any problem. When I run it, on any Python platform, it produces the same error, that is

```
Reloaded modules: plotting
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\PINNs-master\PINNs-master\main\continuous_time_inference (Schrodinger)\Schrodinger.py", line 247, in <module>
    model = PhysicsInformedNN(x0, u0, v0, tb, X_f, layers, lb, ub)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\PINNs-master\PINNs-master\main\continuous_time_inference (Schrodinger)\Schrodinger.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_NN(layers)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\PINNs-master\PINNs-master\main\continuous_time_inference (Schrodinger)\Schrodinger.py", line 111, in initialize_NN
    W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])

  File "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\PINNs-master\PINNs-master\main\continuous_time_inference (Schrodinger)\Schrodinger.py", line 121, in xavier_init
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\random_seed.py", line 35, in _truncate_seed
    return seed % _MAXINT32  # Truncate to fit into 32-bit integer

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Am I just missing something? Someone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: I realize that the user is a novice, but I feel that editing the question down to its minimal reproducible unit would be helpful. Asking good questions is not easy; see [A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or even [B](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Also the idea behind a minimal reproducible example is showing only the code that is pertinent to the problem and question not regurgitating the entire program and all its errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are several general issues with the code:

- Extra `[]`s throughout. They are causing errors and need to be removed.
- The code is written in TensorFlow V1 which has been deprecated. The supported version of TensorFlow is V2. Choosing to use a deprecated version may result in hard to find and fix errors.

Given that preamble, there is one particular bug with the arguments to the `tf.truncated_normal` function. The current code is `tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev)`. [The documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/truncated_normal) states the arguments for that function are: shape, mean, stddev, dtype, and seed. There is an impedance between what the function expects and what it is actually being passed. The result is a misinterpretation of the `seed` value/type and a `TypeError`. I suggest adding passing in all possible arguments as keyword arguments to the `tf.truncated_normal` function.

Something like:

```py
tf.truncated_normal(shape=[in_dim, out_dim], mean=0.0, stddev=xavier_stddev, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=42, name="truncated_normal")
```

Comment: Let me say, "I'm not from a programming background" but I am trying to use PINNs in some of my work. I am now trying to use your suggested solution, I am not sure what you mean by "passing" I have tried to look it up but I can't find a definitive description.

Do you mind, explaining what you mean by 'passing' please?

Comment: @KaRJXEN in programming, the term 'pass X (to a function/method)' means giving X as input to a function/method. For example, if I run the code `my_function(a, b)` , I can say I *pass* `a` and `b` to the `my_function`.

Comment: Anyway, this script seems to run on a very old version of TensorFlow; as quick fix, try replacing `tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)` by `tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32, seed=1)` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @lpounng, Thanks for the description and suggested edit. The error however remains. About the old version of TF, should I just uninstall this one and install a specific version?

Comment: @KaRJXEN strongly suggest to install the correct version; version mismatch is likely the root cause.

Comment: Another possible fix may be replacing `tf.truncated_normal` with `tf.initializers.truncated_normal` (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/truncated_normal_initializer#expandable-2)).